# How to find an instance constructor call in Java debug in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I stopped at some breakpoint in some object instance. I have multiple instances of this class, called in various place.

Is it possible to find that constructor call, which has created namely this instance?

Constructor call is not in stack in the case.

Comment: The constructor call should be in the stacktrace, as long as your breakpoint is inside of the constructor. Conditional breakpoints may help you.

Comment: Namely which instance?

Comment: I assume your class has more than one constructor?  I don't believe there is anything stored in an object that keeps track of which constructor was used when creating the object.  Once the constructor is called and the fields are set up, the constructor is gone--it doesn't leave a record of itself.  Sounds like you need to get the debugger to trap all constructor calls and keep track of which constructor was used for which object.  I don't know how to do that using this debugger.  Maybe someone else does?

Comment: It might be better if you describe your ultimate goal - what is it you want to accomplish by knowing the constructor that was called?

Comment: @ajb no, my class has only one constructor

Comment: In that case I guess I didn't understand your question.  So you're looking for the place in the _rest_ of your code that used `new` to create that particular instance?

Comment: Yes. I see in breakpoint, that some object was created incorrectly and want to trace creation.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible; as @ajb's comment says, the constructor call is long gone by the time the object is used in other ways.

One option you have is to set a breakpoint in the constructor and note the object ID of each instance as it passes through the constructor (Object ID is visible in the **Variables** view, as the value of `this`.

[image]

Then when the other breakpoint is hit, you can look at the ID and know which object it refers to.

Comment: I know this method, but it is hard. Is it possible to automate? As I know, these ids are automatically assigned by eclipse to instances. Why can't it also remember the line of constructor call?

Comment: The ID of an object is assigned by the JVM, not Eclipse. The feature you're looking for simply doesn't exist; I'm not even sure it *could* or *should* exist, to be honest.

Comment: How to print it then?

Comment: I don't know if user code has access to the object IDs, but you could print the `hashCode()` (assuming your classes don't override it).

Comment: `System.identityHashCode(obj)` will work even if the `hashCode()` is overridden.